# Onde fica a pasta com os fontes no servidor? Team Foundation Server

Tags: team-foundation-server

Eu baixei e instalei no servidor da empresa o Team Foundation Server, subi um projeto nele através do Visual Studio e tudo certo.

Gostaria de saber em qual pasta fica o fonte do projeto no servidor? 
Eu procurei e não achei.

https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/tfs/

Obrigado.

Comment: O que você está procurando exatamente e por quê?

Comment: Era para saber onde ficava os fontes para mapear em uma pasta que fazemos backup.

Comment: Você configurou o backup pela ferramenta no Team Foundation Server Administration Console? É a melhor maneira de ter bons backups, e não fazer pelo SQL Server! Qualquer coisa, posta outra pergunta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todos os fontes, definições de build, de release, os artefator (work items) ficam no servidor SQL Server, nada fica em pastas.
Essa é uma feature do TFS, ter tudo em banco de dados, de maneira integrada e com backup.

Comment: Obrigado @egomesbrandao.